# Why can't I get my blob to hold an image binary stream?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert an image to my db using Java, but it seem to not get into.
Here is the code to execute the query

```
String path = "C:\\5X5_type.jpg";
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
ps.setBlob(2, is);
result = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Everything else work, connection adding other staff etc.
But when I try to add this all, I get in my db is the word blob without anything else.
What am I doing wrong?
Edit:
After reading the comments,  I'm using SQuirrel SQL 4.1.0, I had tried setBinaryStream() and I got the same result. I searched for a way to put it manually but didn't find how.

Comment: Try `setBinaryStream()` and please add tag for the DBMS product you are using. The support for blobs in varies substantially between the different JDBC drivers

Comment: Please provide a [mre], specify the database system you're using and provide the DDL of the table you're inserting into.

Answer (score 0):

well I was an idiot, all I had to do is to increase the space to allocate my blob at the data base.